# Biopython unable to declare new SeqRecord

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import re, os
import pandas as pd
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import generic_dna
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
os.chdir('c:\Users\Workspace\Desktop')


filename = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'convertedgisaid','df.dat')
df = pd.read_table(filename, header=None, sep=' ',low_memory=False)
df.columns = ['GID','IsolateID','Carrier','Country','HN','Type','Date','Segment','Gene','Length','ETC','SEQ']

f_in = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'convertedgisaid','annotationFULL.tbl')
f_out = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'convertedgisaid','gisaid_influenza.cds')
file = open(f_in,'r')
records = file.read().split('>Feature ')
file.close()
records = records[1:]
f = open(f_out,'w')
start=1
end=0
for rec in records:
 withoutNewline = re.sub("\n"," ",rec)
 GID = re.match('\d{1,6}',withoutNewline).group()
 Details = df[df.GID==GID]
 Seq = list(Details.SEQ)[0]
 codingSeq=''
 codingDetails = ''
 cdsSegment = re.findall("((?:\d{1,4}   |<\d{1,4}   >|\d{1,4}   >)\d{1,4}   CDS)",withoutNewline)
 for cds in cdsSegment:
  cdsSplit = cds.split('    ')
  if(cdsSplit[0][0]=="<" or cdsSplit[1][0]==">"):
   if(cdsSplit[0][0]=="<"):
    start = cdsSplit[0][1:]
   else:
    start = cdsSplit[0]
   if(cdsSplit[1][0]==">"):
    end = cdsSplit[1][1:]
   else:
    end = cdsSplit[1]
  else:
   start = cdsSplit[0]
   end = cdsSplit[1]
   codingDetails+=cdsSplit[0]+'-'+cdsSplit[1]+','
  codingSeq+=Seq[(int(start)-1):int(end)]
 codingDetails = codingDetails[:-1]
 curSeq = codingSeq.upper()
 curId = GID
 curDesc = ":"+codingDetails+"Influenza "+list(Details.Type)[0]+" virus ("+list(Details.ETC)[0]+" (" +list(Details.HN)[0]+"))"
 cdsRecords = SeqRecord(Seq(curSeq, generic_dna), id=curId, description=curDesc)
 SeqIO.write(cdsRecord,f,"fasta")
f.close()
```

The following code shows the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    TypeError: 'str' object is not callable Topic:Biopython
>   unable to declare new SeqRecord

May I know what is wrong with it? I'm using Bio Python.

Comment: `from Bio import SeqIO` instead of `from Bio import SeqIO\n` works?

Comment: That was a typo from me sorry hahah!

Answer (score 3):

When asking for help on Stackoverflow, always try to reduce your problem to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

If you do this, you would see that you have the following import:

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
```

but further down in your program, you define a variable `Seq` as follows

```
Seq = list(Details.SEQ)[0]
```

So, now `Seq` is no longer the function from `Bio.Seq`, but a string.

So, when you try to do `SeqRecord(Seq(curSeq, generic_dna), id=curId, description=curDesc)` you get a `TypeError` because `Seq`is no longer callable.

So the solution is to rename your `Seq` variable to something else so that it doesn't shadow the imported `Bio.Seq.Seq` any more.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.